# SQL: How to count boolean values by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
Date           Status
2020-03-27     true
2020-03-27     true
2020-03-28     false
2020-03-28     true
```

How can I count the booleans and get a result like this:

```
Date            Success        Failed
2020-03-27      2              0
2020-03-28      1              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select date, sum(status) as success, sum(not status) as failed
from t
group by date;
```

MySQL treats boolean "true" as "1" and boolean false as "0", so `sum()` works on them.

Comment: @user3384512 Are you sure you included the `GROUP BY` line?

Comment: @TheImpaler
 yes

Comment: @user3384512 Please create a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. The Datetime was wrong. Now it works. Thx